# rank of power a linear map $f:V\rightarrow V$ of a vector space V

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$, a linear map $f:V \rightarrow V$ with $\mathrm{rank}f = \mathrm{rank}f^3$. I need some help on how to prove that $\mathrm{rank}f = \mathrm{rank}f^k$ for all $k>3$, $k$ is an integer.

Comment: And what is $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that $f^3(V)=f(f^2(V))\subseteq f(V)$, so if it is given that these spaces have the same (finite) dimension, then they must be equal. It follows that the restriction of $f^2$ to $f(V)$ is bijective, and hence so is the restriction of $f$ to its own image $f(V)$. But then $\def\rk{\operatorname{rk}}\rk(f^k)=\rk(f)$ for all $k\geq1$, which is better than what was asked.

Comment: this statement is what I've been looking for the whole time "It is obvious that $f^3(V)=f(f^2(V))\subseteq f(V)$, so if it is given that these spaces have the same (finite) dimension, then they must be equal". for me it ain't obvious yet though. thanks!

Comment: I hope it is obvious to you that $f^2(V)\subseteq V$; now apply $f$ to both subspaces in the inclusion relation. This is what my sentence you cited was intended to convey.

Comment: Yes it is obvious. I am talking about how a subspace of a vector space is the same as the vector space if they have the same finite dimension. I missed it the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

First, you know that $\operatorname{rank}(f^{3n})=\operatorname{rank}(f)$ for all $n$.  For any $n\geq k$, we have $\operatorname{rank}(f^n)\leq \operatorname{rank}(f^k)$.  Then you have a chain of inequalities:
$$
\operatorname{rank}(f)= \operatorname{rank}(f^{3n})\leq \operatorname{rank}(f^{3n+1})\leq \operatorname{rank}(f^{3n+2})\leq\operatorname{rank}(f^{3n+3})=\operatorname{rank}(f).
$$

Comment: thanks! I've been stucked trying to use a different approach proving $rankf^3 = rank f^2 = rank f$, then using induction on k. Btw, Is it wrong that i assumed $f^2(V)$ is a subspace of $f(V)$?

Comment: @NeilMiguel To answer the question in your comment, it is not wrong. Prove it yourself by writing down the definition of each subspace.

Comment: Hi. How do i prove that $rank(f^{3n}) = rank(f)$ from the fact that $rank(f^3) = rank(f)$. I can see that $f^{3n}(V)$ is a subspace of $f(V)$ but i can't see why they have same dimensions

Comment: @NeilMiguel induction.